# How am I supposed to successfully achieve buffer overflow?

Tags: c, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

I am currently tackling on an assignment, where I need to upload exploit.c and target.c onto a ubuntu server, and successfully achieve a buffer overflow attack with exploit onto target.  I was provided a shellcode.  Now, target.c is not to be altered, just exploit.c.  I had to use GDB on exploit.c to force an external breakpoint on foo() from target.c, to figure out the return addresses using info frame.
I was provided with the working shellcode, and minimal instructions.
I am pretty sure I was able to successfully pull the return addresses, but my issue is that I cannot figure out what code to put into exploit.c to have it successfully perform a buffer overflow attack. I was also instructed that one of the return addresses must be input into the exploit code for it to function properly.
I understand that the exploit is trying to call back to the return address, to then push itself into the buffer, so I can obtain access to the shell.

Here is exploit.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "shellcode.h"

// replace this define environment to have the correct path of your own target code
#define TARGET "/*******************"

int main(void)
{
  char *args[3];
  char *env[2];
  char *tmp = NULL;

  // Creating an input buffer that can cause buffer overflow in strcpy function in the target.c executable code
  int buffSize = 1000; 
  char buff[buffSize]; 
  // Intialize buffer elements to 0x01
  int i;  
   for (i=0; i < buffSize; i++)     buff[i] = 0x01;

  // write your code below to fill the 22 bytes shellcode into the buff variable, and 
  // at the correct location overwrite the return address correctly in order to achieve stack overflow
  // Your own code starts here:
 
  strcpy (buff[buffSize-22], shellcode);


  
  
  
  
  // Your code ends here.
  
  // prepare command line input to execute target code
  args[0] = TARGET; // you must have already compiled and generated the target executable code first
  args[1] = buff; // the first input parameter to the target code (artfully crafted buffer overflow string)
  args[2] = NULL;
  env[0] = "FOO=bar"; 
  env[1] = NULL;

  if (0 > execve(TARGET, args, env))
    fprintf(stderr, "execve failed.\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Here is the  target.c code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int foo(char* arg)
{
  char localBuf[240];
  short len = 240;
  float var1=2.4;  
  int *ptr = NULL;
  strcpy(localBuf, arg);
  printf("foo() finishes normally.\n");
  return 0;
}

int kbhit(void)
{
  struct timeval tv;
  fd_set read_fd;
  tv.tv_sec=0;  tv.tv_usec=0;
  FD_ZERO(&read_fd);  FD_SET(0,&read_fd);
  if(select(1, &read_fd, NULL, NULL, &tv) == -1)
    return 0;
  if(FD_ISSET(0,&read_fd))
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "target: argc != 2\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  printf("Press any key to call foo function...\n");
  while(!kbhit())
    ;
  foo(argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled both target and exploit.  Then I ran GDB on exploit, and formed a breakpoint using "break target.c:10".  Using Info Frame I was able to obtain the return addresses.

I used strcpy, because it is essentially the only line of code we were taught for this section involving overflow attacks, even though it clearly states in the document "Fill the shell executable code (in the string array shellcode[]) byte-by-
byte into the buff for your modified return address to execute, do not
use strcpy() because shellcode[] is not an ASCII string (and not
copying NULL byte, too)."

Exploit compiles fine, and it runs fine, but it does not give me access to a shell.  I was instructed that I would know if it worked, if I was presented with two dollar signs ($$) instead of one ($).

I am a network engineer, and I am not entirely savvy with C, or attacking vulnerabilities in programs, any help would be appreciated. The entire lesson revolves around "stack overflow", but this assignment is called "buffer overflow attack".

Comment: just scanning, use [`memcpy`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) instead of `strcpy`. As it says, `strcpy` will stop once it hits a NUL terminator. Don't treat binary data like string data, might get lucky a few times but you'll get burned eventually. This shellcode doesn't have a NUL byte, so it will (ironically) keep copying beyond the bounds of `shellcode`.

Comment: Looking at target.c, it seems the overflow is on a 240 byte buffer allocated on the stack. So I'm guessing you need to put your shellcode somewhere near 240 bytes into the first argument to target. But your exploit is putting it more near 1000 bytes into it. Or your shellcode can stay where it is, but you need to put the address of it into ~240 bytes into the buffer.